Draw a tree with custom graphics and coordinates
I am trying to make a Mathematica version of the following binary tree:

I want the nodes and lines to be represented by Graphics[] objects (Disks and Lines, I guess). The disk size should change with the row. If the topmost row disk has radius 1, then the $N^{th}$ row disk should have radius $1/2^N$.
Here is a code snippet specifying the (x,y) coordinates for 4 rows:
Table[{m/2^n, -n}, {n, 0, 3}, {m, -2^n + 1, 2^n - 1}];

I can draw the nodes, but I cannot figure out how to draw the lines connecting the nodes. Could someone please help?
---------------- Adding a second part ------------------
If I want to convert the tree to polar coordinates, how would I go about it? It should like like this:

Thus $x \to \theta$ living in $(-\pi,\pi)$ $(0,2\pi)$, while $y \to r$ extending out to infinity.
I am sorry, it was not evident to me how to extend your answers to this polar version.

I just added an extension to my question. I hope you will be able to help with that as well.

Thannk you all for the great answers. I selected one as the Answer, but the others worked too. I learnt a lot about Mathematica in the process. Cheers!

KaryTree and VertexShapeFunction
n=5;
vf[{xc_,yc_},name_,{w_,h_}]:=Disk[{xc,yc},2^(-Floor[Log[2,name]])]; 
KaryTree[2^n-1,VertexShapeFunction -> vf]


Or, in another layout:
n=10;
vf[{xc_,yc_},name_,{w_,h_}]:=Disk[{xc,yc},0.5*2^(-Floor[Log[2,name]])];
KaryTree[2^n-1,VertexShapeFunction->vf,GraphLayout->"RadialEmbedding"]



But this does not generalise well for larger n. Try out n=10 and see. There is something iffy about the graph.

Oh, you needed $n=10$ case. Please indicate in advance :-)

Haha, arbitrary n would be nice.

I present a shortcut only that relies on built-in functionality.
Clear["Global`*"];

col = \!\(\*
TagBox[
StyleBox[
RowBox[{"RGBColor", "[", 
RowBox[{"0.08232387729925233`", ",", "0.37641502636977564`", ",", 
        "0.5097322184978276`"}], "]"}],
ShowSpecialCharacters->False,
ShowStringCharacters->True,
NumberMarks->True],
FullForm]\);
n = 5;
divs = 2^# & /@ Range[0, n - 1];
nodedivs = TakeList[Range[2^n - 1], divs];
vsizes = 3 (1/2^# & /@ Range[0, n - 1]);
vsizesRules = Thread /@ Thread[nodedivs -> vsizes] // Catenate;

k5 = CompleteKaryTree[n
  , VertexShapeFunction -> ({EdgeForm[{Thick, Black}], col, 
      Disk[#, #3]} &)
  , VertexSize -> vsizesRules
  (*,VertexLabels\[Rule]"Name"*)
  , VertexStyle -> col
  , EdgeStyle -> Directive @@ {Thick, Darker@col}
  , ImageSize -> 600
  , AspectRatio -> 1/2
  ]




EDIT
VertexCoordinates can be defined using CirclePoints:
Clear["Global`*"];

col = \!\(\*
TagBox[
StyleBox[
RowBox[{"RGBColor", "[", 
RowBox[{"0.08232387729925233`", ",", "0.37641502636977564`", ",", 
        "0.5097322184978276`"}], "]"}],
ShowSpecialCharacters->False,
ShowStringCharacters->True,
NumberMarks->True],
FullForm]\);
n = 5;
divs = 2^# & /@ Range[0, n - 1];
nodedivs = TakeList[Range[2^n - 1], divs];
vsizes = 3/2 (1/2^# & /@ Range[0, n - 1]);
vsizesRules = Thread /@ Thread[nodedivs -> vsizes] // Catenate;
rt = MapAt[# + 1 &, Transpose[{ Range[0, (n - 1)], divs}], {2 ;;, 1}];
cpoints = CirclePoints @@@ rt // Catenate;

CompleteKaryTree[n
   , VertexShapeFunction -> ({EdgeForm[{Thick, Black}], col, 
           Disk[#, #3]} &)
  , VertexSize -> vsizesRules
   (*,VertexLabels\[Rule]"Name"*)
   , VertexStyle -> col
   , EdgeStyle -> Directive @@ {Thick, Darker@col}
   , ImageSize -> 600
   , AspectRatio -> 1
 , VertexCoordinates -> Thread[Range[1, 2^n - 1] -> cpoints]
 , Epilog -> {Dashed, Circle[{0, 0}, #] & /@ Range[1, n]}
 ]


I have left dashed circles so that it is more obvious where the points landed.


To create the tree, we first create the coordinates: co of the disks:
n = 3;
xs = 0.5 Table[x, {x, 2^n}];
xs = NestList[Mean /@ Partition[#, 2] &, xs, n];
co = Table[{xs[[i, j]], 0.7 i}, {i, n + 1}, {j, Length[xs[[i]]]}]

Then we create the radii, disks and lines:
rad = 0.4 Reverse[Table[1/2^i, {i, 0, n}]];
disk = Table[
   Disk[co[[i, j]], rad[[i]]], {i, n + 1}, {j, Length[xs[[i]]]}];
lines = Table[
   Line[{{co[[i, j]], co[[i - 1, 2 j - 1]]}, {co[[i, j]], 
      co[[i - 1, 2 j]]}}], {i, 2, n + 1}, {j, Length[xs[[i]]]}];

Finally we create the tree:
Graphics[{disk, lines}]



Can you please explain what NestList[Mean /@ Partition[#, 2] &, xs, n]; does? It is a dense line.

Thank you for this very readable solution, by the way.

xs are the x coordinates of the lowest line." NestList" creates the x coordinates of the lines above. "Partition" takes pairs of x coordinates  of the predecessor line and Mean takes the  mean of these pairs.
